# What information can be gained from the the density or the distribution of outliers in box plots?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-visualization, dataset, boxplot

[image]Hi everyone, I am using box plots to show my results for the simulated energy consumptions. However, the distributions of the outliers for the months May and June are weird to me. Specially considering the small IQR.Can someone please explain, what can the distribution and the density of the outliners indicate?
I also did the same plots with violin plots! [image]

Comment: There is obviously some interesting pattern in the data, which has to do with what the boxplot rules call an outlier. However, the visualization as boxplot tells little about these outliers, as they become black lines instead of individual dots. My first recommendation would be to draw the same picter as a violin plot instead of a boxplot. The violin plot does not distinguish between inlier and outlier data and would give you a better impression on how many of the data points are below and above that gap in the middle.

Comment: @Bernhard I actually thought the same, to try the violin plots! Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked whether these high outliers all correspond to the same customer month after month?  That seems likely and, if so, it means you can identify a subpopulation that has almost constant large heating requirements over time.  Singling out that subpopulation for separate analysis would improve your results.

Comment: It is interesting that the violin plots are noticeably worse than the boxplots in displaying the gaps in all the distributions.

Comment: @whuber plotting them did not help at all.

Comment: Why not?  What did the plot look like?